Cannot resolve "missing" Djanjo when trying to run label-studio
I want to use the popular package label-studio to build training data using images that I'll apply the AI labelling steps on.
The problem is that after cloning the repo from github and following all the instructions, I'm getting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/markalsip/label-studio/label_studio/manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.conf import settings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/markalsip/label-studio/label_studio/manage.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

The first problem is that django IS installed and my PYTHONPATH environment variable, by all means at my disposal, is correct:
django-admin --version

returns:  3.2.25
echo $PYTHONPATH

returns: /Users/markalsip/label-studio/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages:
I should point out the instructions for this program indicate I should run it in what I believe to be a virtual environment. I have done this (my current root folder is Marks-MBP:label-studio, thus the text shown in the prompt):
Marks-MBP:label-studio markalsip$ source /Users/markalsip/label-studio/env/bin/activate
(env) Marks-MBP:label-studio markalsip$ python --version

returns: Python 3.12.0
To run the python program, I am told to:
python label_studio/manage.py runserver

I should back up and say that ALL of the things I'm doing here, such as checking paths, environment variables, etc., is done while I'm in this environment. I got there by the command:
source /Users/markalsip/label-studio/env/bin/activate

What I've tried:

Uninstalling and reinstalling django
Uninstalling and reinstalling the label_studio
Listed installed packages from both the command line, as well as directly accessing them (e.g. the django django-admin --version, wbich returns 3.2.25)

Verifying my environment variable don't look wonky. My entire .bash_profile is pretty simplistic:
# Setting PATH for Python 3.12
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:${PATH}"
PYTHONPATH="/Users/markalsip/label-studio/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
export PATH
export PYTHONPATH

I also found a recommendation to ensure there are no .txt files in the label program source folder that list additional dependencies. I find no such file.
I saw a note during the install process that django itself had two dependencies. I checked and both of those are installed.
EDIT EDIT EDIT
Following the suggestions in comments, I first saw the django wasn't in the environment path I set up, so I backed up, created a new environment, installed django, and verified that it is indeed in the path suggested in the comments. I've installed all packages "clean" in this new environment.
The error I now receive is similar to the last one, but a bit different:
(venv) Marks-MBP:label-studio markalsip$ python label_studio/manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/markalsip/label-studio/label_studio/manage.py", line 11, in 
from django.conf import settings
File "/Users/markalsip/label-studio/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/init.py", line 19, in 
from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango60Warning
File "/Users/markalsip/label-studio/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 4, in 
from asgiref.sync import iscoroutinefunction, markcoroutinefunction, sync_to_async
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asgiref'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/markalsip/label-studio/label_studio/manage.py", line 18, in 
raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
(venv) Marks-MBP:label-studio markalsip$
I'm clearly in a virtual environment. My PYTHONPATH is as follows:
(venv) Marks-MBP:label-studio markalsip$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/Users/markalsip/label-studio/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages:
A listing of the site-packages folder:
drwxr-xr-x  12 markalsip  staff  384 Aug 26 16:57 Django-5.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  21 markalsip  staff  672 Aug 26 16:57 django
drwxr-xr-x   9 markalsip  staff  288 Aug 26 16:57 pip
drwxr-xr-x  11 markalsip  staff  352 Aug 26 16:57 pip-23.2.1.dist-info
So django IS THERE.
I did find a somewhat related post that suggested I try the following:
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=core.settings.label_studio
So I've tried that from within the environment but it didn't make a difference.
The one thing that's worrisome is the very last line:
(venv) Marks-MBP:site-packages markalsip$ django-admin --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/django-admin", line 5, in 
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
File "/Users/markalsip/label-studio/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 17, in 
from django.conf import settings
File "/Users/markalsip/label-studio/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/init.py", line 19, in 
from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango60Warning
File "/Users/markalsip/label-studio/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 4, in 
from asgiref.sync import iscoroutinefunction, markcoroutinefunction, sync_to_async
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asgiref'
I'm now trying to find out what the heck asgiref is and why I was never asked to install or otherwise reference it with django

Have you been pip install-ing all your packages while the virtual environment is active? If not, try that and see if it works.

ls /Users/markalsip/label-studio/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages - is there a django directory there?

If you do python -m django, does it find it?

answering backwards from order received: python3 -m djano does show it is there, but I see this warning. I confess I don't know much about django; I simply installed it with pip because it was required:
Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured (error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.).

If I do the ls /Users/markalsip/label-studio/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages  I do NOT see django. So apparently it is installed on my system but not where this environment thinks it should be... working back now and will try Andrew's suggestion to install all in the environment. I THINK I did that, but let me make sure

Getting an error but slightly different. The message is too long for a comment. I have incorporated all three suggestions. I'll update my original question to reflect what's happening now. This is driving me nuts. Really appreciate the help

So to follow up on the revisions made in my edit of the OP, I've implemented the suggestions here, and made progress. Buried in the error messages that only seem to reveal detail after I've made a change, I'm discovering the labelling program I'm trying to run relies on SPECIFIC versions of django & other packages, which themselves require SPECIFIC (or should I say maximum?) versions of packages that packages require. I'm now sorting through this mess. Some documentation hints that I should have found a text doc in the label program folder listing dependencies, but alas, this is not the case.
